# SharePoint 2010 forms with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to create forms for SharePoint using VS2010, or is that fulfilled by InfoPath 2010?

Answer (score 1):

If you are customizing list forms, you have two options: 1) Classic ASPX Pages (like out of the box forms) 2) InfoPath forms

For first option, you use VS2010 and InfoPath 2010 for 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find a great deal about the ASPX route, and for example, can't see anywhere to edit my workflows task approval page. Could you point me towards any good tutorials regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about custom workflow association form, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563325.aspx. Also on the same page, other "How To" links are present.  If you want to customize the task forms, you may find this useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550938.aspx